# 1 day old documents get from mongodb

Tags: javascript, linux, bash, mongodb

I am trying to get the previous day's documents from MongoDB using bash script and JavaScript.

I used JS to pass the query to MongoDB but there's an issue when I get the date because it is like this:

> 2015-7-3  6:2:00

but in my db records are like this:

> 2015-07-03 06:02:00

```
var d = new Date();
db.mycoll.find({ "requestedDateTime" : { $gte :d.getFullYear()+'-'+(d.getUTCMonth() + 1)+'-'+(d.getDate() - 1)+' 06:00:00' }});
```

The above query is how I run it now, this needs to run every day in the cronjob too.
If there is any way to do it without using JS, I would love to learn it too.

Answer (score 1):

Just use date math

```
var today = new Date(),
    yesterday = new Date( today.valueOf() - ( 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 );
```

Or rounded to the start of day UTC:

```
var date = new Date(),
    today = new Date( date.valueOf() - ( date.valueOf() % ( 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 ) ) ),
    yesterday = new Date( today.valueOf() - ( 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 ) );
```

Then pass into the query:

```
db.mycoll.find({ "requestedDate": { "$gte": yesterday, "$lt": today } });
```

So either 24 hours from the excution time, or 24 hours in the previous day. Take you pick depending on which you want.

Comment: I appreciate you effort on helping me .  unfortunately this doesn't work it will deliver iso date and it wan't work with db .** "requestedDateTime" : "2015-07-02 15:10:21"** this is how date in mongodb

Comment: @DarshanaKapuge Dates in MongoDB are `Date` objects and not strings as you seem to be trying to do. You need to use a `Date` object. Believe me I do know this. Unless of course your dates are stored as strings, which is "soo very wrong". You should be fixing the dates stored in the collection.